# countuniqueifs one condition and not-another condition

Tags: google-sheets

In my sheet, Column G will either indicate "LIKE Submission" or "Incident Referral." Columns D-E-F list different names (one per row). I want to tally the number of unique names where the row contains "Incident Referral" for Column G and there are NO instances of "LIKE Submission."

This is a sample of my data:[image]

Thus far, I've attempted `=COUNTUNIQUEIFS(Referrals!D:D, Referrals!E:E, Referrals!F:F, Referrals!G17:G, "Incident Referral", Referrals!G17:G, "<>*LIKE Submission*")`, but the result doesn't check out what I expect to obtain from my test.

In the example on the image above, I would expect the result to evaluate to 1 (i.e. only "Stark, Tony" has an "Incident Referral" AND no "LIKE Submission").All help will be well received!

Answer (score 0):

Use `query()` with an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) to get the relevant data, another `query()` to get unique names in those interim results, and finally `rows()` to calculate the number of unique names, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  rows( 
    query( 
      transpose( 
        query( 
          { G2:G, D2:D & E2:E & F2:F }, 
          "select Col1, count(Col1) 
           where Col1 = 'Incident Referral' or Col1 = 'LIKE Submission' 
           group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0 
        ) 
      ), 
      "where Col2 >= 1 and Col3 is null", 0 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```